# some ssh port forwarding operations not permitted, interactive ok, after client upgrade

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, cygwin

- Host: `Amazon Linux with OpenSSH 6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015`
- Client: `Win 10 with Cygwin OpenSSH 7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`

I can ssh interactively with no problem:

```
win10$ ssh user@example.com
aws$
```

This port forwarding also works:

```
win10$ ssh -NTL 9003:localhost:80 user@example.com &
win10$
```

I use the latter to access phpmyadmin on the server through:

```
http://phpmyadmin.localhost:9003
```

That works fine.

In order to use netbeans to debug php code running on the server, I do:

```
win10$ ssh -NTR 9000:localhost:9000 user@example.com &
```

This used to work okay. But after upgrading Cygwin, I now get:

```
ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Operation not permitted
```

Adding a -vvvv to the command line doesn't give much more information:

```
win10$ ssh -vvvv -NTR 9000:localhost:9000 user@example.com
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug2: resolving "example.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to example.com [nn.nn.nn.nn] port 22.
debug1: connect to address nn.nn.nn.nn port 22: Operation not permitted
ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Operation not permitted
```

I believe that the previous version of ssh that worked for me doing this was `Cygwin on WinXP with OpenSSH 7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f, 28 Jan 2016`

Nothing has changed on the server. Since port 9000 is not privileged, I don't think it should be a permission problem, especially since the server config hasn't changed, but I have to admit that port forwarding is basically magic to me. Any ideas what might be wrong or how to collect more/better information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer, it's just what I have observed. I rebooted my Win10 PC, which applied some updates that were pending. I also have Eset Internet Security installed on it, with firewall filtering mode set to interactive. After the reboot, when I tried the forwarding that previously failed, Eset prompted that ssh.exe had been modified and asked if it was okay to keep the rules allowing it to initiate traffic. I said it was okay, and then it started working again. Before the reboot, Eset had no complaints. And as noted, the forwarding for port 9003 worked okay.

I don't know what to take away from this as a learning experience, other than the usual Windows mantra from XP days of "run Windows Update, and reboot frequently" but the problem is now resolved!

Comment: Restart worked for me on Mac